# Generate two random integers have remainder 0 when first is divided by second integer

Tags: java, oop

Hi I need to generate two random integers such that if I divide the first integer by second integer, the reminder should be 0. I'm looking for approach to do this. Also both integers should be greater than 0

```
Random rnd=new Random();
int firstNum=rnd.nextInt();
int secondNum=rnd.nextInt();
//Some efficient calculations here to make firstNum % secondNum equals 0.
```

> I want **firstNum % secondNum** equals **0**.

Comment: What if the first random integer is a prime?  Here's a simple algorithm: 1) Choose the first integer randomly; 2) Build a list of all divisors of that number; 2) Choose one of those divisors randomly.

Comment: Yes. I agree to this solution but this needs more computations. Is this more efficient way to do that?
Thanks for your answer :-)

Comment: NO. The set of valid answers for the second number is only the divisors of the first number. You could try numbers randomly until you found one but that could take a _very_ long time, especially if the first number was a large prime number.  The fastest way by far is to factor the first number, build a list of factors and choose one randomly, assuming the second number must be a random choice.

Comment: I would go about it the other way. Pick two random integers, and _multiply_ them. Then your two numbers are (1) the product and (2) the first random number. Since you got that product by multiplying the first number by an integer, you know that the first number divides that product.

Comment: @yshavit Your situation will always generate 0 but the firstNum/secondNum will always equal to firstNum. But I keep your suggestions, I can introduce a thirdNum which will bye used that how many times it is multiplied. I hope this will work for me. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Maybe I should explain what I meant in more detail, in an answer below. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple algorithm:

1. Choose the first integer randomly
2. Factor the fist integer and build a list of all divisors of that number
3. Choose one of those divisors randomly

The only valid choices for the second number are divisors of the first number. The set of possible choices can be as small as 2 if the first number is a prime, or zero if 1`and the number itself are not acceptable answers (you haven't specified).

An alternative is to just generate random numbers for the second number and check if they divide the first number, but that could take a ***very*** long time, especially if the first number was a large prime number.  Not recommended.

Comment: Great solution. Thanks for your help sir. Don't know why others are down voting my question

Comment: @RashidAbbas Probably because you didn't demonstrate any effort at solving it yourself, which can give the impression that you're lazy and expect others to do your work for you.

Comment: @shmosel Thanks. I'll keep care next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
There is a very simple answer to your problem.

create a method which generates two random numbers using Random class. And also declare two variables at class level.



int a,b;    

void compute()
    {
    Random r1=new Random();

    //nextInt method will generate two numbers between a range, here from 1 to 1000
    this.a=r1.nextInt(1000)+1;
    this.b=r1.nextInt(1000)+1;

    //now check if the desired numbers gives 0 when dividing a by b.

    if(a%b==0)
    {
    Sys.out(this.a+" and "+this.b);
    }
    else
    {
    compute();
    }
}


call this method and it will run till you find two numbers which gives remainder 0.
```

This approach may be little more time taking than others but it fits the basic concept of your question because it is generating two random numbers irrespective of knowledge of other number, hence it doesn't care if the number is prime, odd or even. It'll give you two numbers which divides each other giving remainder 0.

Comment: This can easily cause a stack overflow.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. Amateur error as i am a beginner. Now I have corrected it.

Comment: You're still calling `compute()` recursively.

Comment: That is not a problem now. Because i am over writing values of a and b each time compute is called. Hence no stackoverflow error.

Comment: What's the connection?

Comment: OP asked to create two random numbers which when dividing each other should give 0. My code will print that without any error. I dont know what are you talking about now.

Comment: I'm quite aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can give limits to the firstNumber and secondNumber then you can try below solution.

```
public static void Main()
    {
        var random = new Random();
        int firstNo = random.Next(800);
        int secondNo = random.Next(400);

        while(firstNo % secondNo != 0)
        {
             secondNo = random.Next(400);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(firstNo);
        Console.WriteLine(secondNo);
    }
}
```

The second random number's seed is 400 because the divisors of a number are always either that number itself or any number half its value.

Maybe you can modify this to fit your scenario.

Comment: That's not Java.

Comment: You can use a do/while to avoid repeating `secondNo = random.Next(400);`.

Comment: I believe that our imagination should never limit to languages, they should be able to just grasp the idea and then you can take that idea and mold it in any manner you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would turn the algorithm very slightly on its head.

What you want is two integers, both with some sort of randomness (independently from each other), such that firstNumber / secondNumber = K + 0, where K is some integer. But if you solve for firstNumber, that means that firstNumber = secondNumber * K. So rather than generating secondNumber directly, generate K.

1. Choose secondNumber as a random int. A good way to do this is with [`Random#nextInt(int bound) + 1`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) (you need the `+ 1` because `nextInt` may return 0).
2. Choose *K* as a random int, similarly to in the previous step.
3. Calculate firstNumber as secondNumber * K. Now discard K; you don't need it any more.

Now you have your two numbers. You know that secondNumber / firstNumber has remainder 0, because secondNumber / firstNumber = K, where K is that second random integer you picked.